2024 Election Results: Congratulations to our new moderator!
The 2024 elections are over. By analyzing the OpaSTV file with the voting data, I'd like to welcome to the moderators' team the winner of the 2024 moderator elections, who is:
Shaun
In the name of all the users on Mathematics SE, congratulations on your victory!
You can view a summary report of the election on OpaVote.
We would also like to take the opportunity to express our endless gratitude to quid once again for their great service to this community over the years.

Congratulations Shaun. Use your powers wisely.

Thank you all so much. I'm very surprised, as there were some strong candidates. I will do my utmost to serve the community. I'm humbled.

Thank you, @quid, for your service.

Congratulations, Shaun!

Thank you, @RobertFrost.

Thank you, @amWhy.

As always, @Asaf, you rock wrt your speedy election results!

Yes, well done, @AsafKaragila. Thank you.

Congratulations  @Shaun.  In $2022$, I nominated you for moderator, but this time you  got what you deserved.

Congratulations, welcome to the team.

This is indescribable. I'm elated!
Thank you to all who voted for me, first choice or otherwise. (I don't see why you did!) As I said in the comments, there were some strong candidates this year.
I'll do my best, as @quid is a tough act to follow.

Congratulations.

Congratulations

Congratulations, Shaun!

Man, who down votes something like this? Regardless, Shaun, congratulations, and best of luck moderating!

Best of luck! Try to balance this with real life :-)

Congratulations shaun, Please tell if You receive some merch from stack exchange...

Thank you. I haven't, @DheerajGujrathi.

I voted for you!  It's exciting to see that my vote counted.

Congratulations!

Thank you, @OlexandrKonovalov; it was great to meet you this last week! :)

Congratulations !
